# when I try to do eas build I get A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBHMz.png)

Any suggestions on how I can solve this error when I try to build?

I'm on a mac m1 when I run expo-doctor it has no errors.

Attach the image of the error in expo where the error is thrown specifically in the gradlew run.